# Yosys Can't open include file

Tags: verilog, yosys

I am getting a `Can't open include file` error with yosys.  Is there a command line argument to define include directories and/or is there a default directory it is looking for include files in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include directories can be passed as arguments to `read_verilog`:

```
read_verilog -Ipath/to/includes rtl/main.v
read_verilog -Ipath/to/includes rtl/stuff.v
```

Alternatively the command `verilog_defaults` can be used to set options for all subsequent calls to `read_verilog`. For example:

```
verilog_defaults -add -Ipath/to/includes
read_verilog rtl/main.v
read_verilog rtl/stuff.v
```

By default, `read_verilog` is looking for include files in the current working directory and in the directory that contains the verilog file with the `` `include `` statement.

---

Edit re. the comments:

I have created the following example:

```
$ cat a.v 
`include "b.v"
module test;
initial $display(`message);
endmodule

$ cat b.v 
`define message "Hello World!"
```

I can successfully run this with `yosys -p "read_verilog a.v"` as well as with `yosys a.v`. Please edit the question so it includes an example where processing of the include files fails.

Comment: the file was in the current directory that yosys was run and all the files, will try these suggestions and see what that does, thanks!

Comment: okay I think between your comments and different command line examples that has it.  was doing the thing from the hackaday example yosys -p "synth_ice40 -blif out.blif" a.v b.v c.v  and that had the include problem, but if you yosys -p "read_verilog a.v; read_verilog b.v; read_verilog c.v; synth_ice40 -blif out.blif" then no problems it finds the include file.

Comment: hmm, replacing always @(stuff) with always @* was the problem, going back to always @(stuff) the design builds completely, with the include, thanks!

Comment: @dwelch hmm... please include an example for that in the question. `always @(stuff)` and `always @*` should do the same (when stuff does not contain any posedge/negedge), and it certainly should not interfere with the processing of include files..

Comment: there were posedges in a couple and that is likely the issue.  was hacking and slashing to see if I could mess with resource usage or play with opt, I suspect I just broke the design is all...